# unable to update package base64enc after update to R to 3.5.0

Tags: r, sendmailr

This is the first time I post a question here, however I have found many answers here already. Thanks for that.

We upgraded R on our Linux server to version 3.5.0 recently and now I am unable to use the sendmailR package. I have reinstalled the packages like I did for other packages, but the base64enc package on which sendmailR is dependent seems not updated.

> library(sendmailR)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sendmailR’:
>    package ‘base64enc’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version

I have tried to manually update the base64enc package, this does not give any error, but I keep getting the above errormessage when loading sendmailR.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Run `update.packages()`.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall it and reinstall it afterword

Comment: Yes, I have tried to remove it and then reinstall it without success.

Comment: I did an update.packages just now again. After running install.packages for stringi (because there was a problem with that package) the only error I get is: ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’. But when loading the sendmailR package the problem is not fixed.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin: Your solution did work! I now see that the package base64enc was in my User Library instead of in the System Library. And I didn't realize it.